# Vaadin23 PUSH UIDetachedException

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I have the following broadcast handler in the `MainLayout`

```
@Override
protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
    super.onAttach(attachEvent);

    SecurityService securityService = serviceFacade.getSecurityService();
    UI ui = attachEvent.getUI();
    if (securityService.isAuthorized()) {
        broadcasterRegistration = serviceFacade.getBroadcasterService().register(securityService.getCurrentUserUuid(), broadcasterMessage -> {
            ui.access(() -> {
                processBroadcasterMessage(broadcasterMessage);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

and from time to time I see the following exception in the logs:

```
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-5" com.vaadin.flow.component.UIDetachedException
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.handleAccessDetach(UI.java:415)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.access(UI.java:515)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.access(UI.java:502)
    at com.example.ui.layout.MainLayout.lambda$onAttach$2(MainLayout.java:331)
    at com.example.ui.service.broadcaster.BroadcasterServiceImpl.lambda$broadcast$0(BroadcasterServiceImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Despite the fact of this exception everything works properly, so my question is - should I react somehow on this `UIDetachedException` exception or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIDetachedException` serves a purpose. It is thrown when you attempt to access closed UI. User has closed the Browser. You should catch the exception, e.g. stop the background task, unregister the broadcast listener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please tell the scenario how to reproduce it locally? I can't reproduce it to handle it (

Comment: Could you just check UI#isAttached inside of the #access class instead of catching the exception?

Comment: sure, thanks! I'll add this check also